# Consuming WCF in Xamarin forms

Tags: wcf, xamarin, mono

I am generating a WCF proxy using add web referance in Xamarin Studio
yet genrated proxy create the following error:

> The type or namespace name `IExtensibleDataObject' does not exist in the namespace`System.Runtime.Serialization'. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0234) (infra)

I am using mono4.0.5

Can anybody help me solve this problem that gave me many sleepless nights.

PS: I tried to skip proxy generation to using `slsvcutil.exe` code generation
but the same error keeps happening

Comment: have you included every thing the slsvcutil.exe generates. It includes the System.Runtime.Serailization dll also.

Comment: no it did'nt generate this file

Comment: it didnt generate dll for me

Comment: Are you using PCL or Shared?@MohamadKamal

Answer (score 0):

Right click on you project and select Edit references. Look for System.Runtime.Serialization and select it.

Answer (score 0):

If you already set the reference of System.Runtime.Serailization and error is still persist then try following regular steps..

1. clean solution and rebuild solution
2. restart visual studio

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for your problem. The problem is Xamarin Portable Targets. The targets must not contain any Windows targets selected. After changing this as in the image below it will not give you any compile time errors for System.Runtime.Serialization.

[image]

I found that after reading this https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/assemblies/

The System.Runtime.Serialization.dll is for the Silverlight package and when selecting windows targets it might be removing these dlls/code not supported in windows platform from the portable libraries.